# Combine List of like DataTables

Tags: c#, linq

I know this could be done manually with some hardcoded Linq Joins.  However, I would **like** to come up with an elegant way to do this in bulk due to the high number of .csv files I have.

Code:

```
var dir = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\IIP_2\", "*.csv", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
var dtCombined = new DataTable();
var lst = new List<DataTable>();

foreach (var v in dir) { lst.Add(GetCSVRows(v, true)); }

//Take List<DataTable> and combine into dtCombined ????
```

How can I combine this List into one, possibly with a Lambda statement ?

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work for you?  You should be able to avoid use the list of DataTables altogether.

```
foreach (var v in dir) 
{ 
    dtCombined.Merge(GetCSVRows(v, true)); 
}
```

If you change GetCSVRows to return an `IDataReader`, you can use [Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x8ccbsb), which *may* be faster.

```
foreach (var v in dir) 
{ 
    dtCombined.Load(GetCSVRows(v, true)); 
}
```

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on good csv reader.  The one I'm using is throwing type errors on dates ?

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna: I don't but I know there are questions here about it.